log4j Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null"
I have been struggling with issues regarding lo4j and getting my logging. After a lot of frustration, I went to the apache website: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/getting-started.html and copied the default log4j.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns="https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns"
               xsi:schemaLocation="
                       https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns
                       https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns/log4j-config-2.xsd">

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE">
      <JsonTemplateLayout/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.mycompany" level="INFO"/>
    <Root level="WARN">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>

Doing so resulted in the following errors:
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 6 and column 79
log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 6 and column 79
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I'm using log4j 2.24.2. Is this a bug or a doc bug?
I'm using java 8 under tomcat 9.

You called the file log4j.xml instead of log4j2.xml. Only Log4j 1 looks for files called log4j.xml and the file is in Log4j 2 format.

@PiotrP.Karwasz was a log4j version that it was colliding with so it required log4j.xml. It was pretty confusing

The error appears to be because I had an older version of lo4j that was getting included by one of the packages maven was bringing in for me. I had log4j-1.2.16.jar in my lib directory.
I simply stopped my webapp, deleted this jar, and restarted and started getting all kinds of log messages.
